# Airdrop Won't Airdrop to certain device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, airdrop

I have a personal computer (MBP mid-2015), work computer (MBP 2018), iPad Air 2, iPhone 7plus, iPhone 8. All devices can send and receive Airdrop items except for the mid-2015 MBP. It will only Airdrop with the other MBP. Anyone have an idea why or how to fix? I can Airdrop from all of the other devices perfectly, but the mid-2015 has always had this issue, from the moment I got it brand new.

Comment: Apple has a quick troubleshooting guide at the bottom of this page  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106

Comment: I'm not saying that Apple make it unreliable on purpose because they want you to buy a newer one, but the new iOS update just made my Macbook 2015 and iPhone airdrop no longer see each other....